# Is `1 XOR 1 OR 1` ambiguous in Boolean algebra?

Tags: math, boolean-logic

Using boolean algebra (not a specific language implementation), can we evaluate `1 ^ 1 + 1` (or `1 XOR 1 OR 1`) unambiguously?

I can derive two evaluations:

```
 [I]:  (1 ^ 1) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
[II]:  1 ^ (1 + 1) = 1 ^ 1 = 0
```

Perhaps there's some stated order of operations, or of a left-to-right evaluation? Or is this not defined in Boolean algebra?

Comment: It depends on the grammar of the language.  It could be either.

Comment: @Akroy: Well it's a great question either way. Tidied it up slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [the rules of boolean algebra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BooleanAlgebra.html) to attempt to evaluate the expression `1 XOR 1 OR 1`.

Now:

- `XOR` is derived from `OR` such that `A XOR B = (¬A AND B) OR (¬B AND A)`;
- Associativity tells us that `A OR (B OR C) = (A OR B) OR C`;
- Associativity also tells us that `A AND (B AND C) = (A AND B) AND C`

So, taking either of the possible interpretations of evaluation order:

```
  (1 XOR 1) OR 1                       1 XOR (1 OR 1)
```

Even though we have no left-to-right "evaluation order" defined, these rules are all we need to show that the two possible interpretations are *not* equivalent:

```
= (¬1 AND 1) OR (¬1 AND 1) OR 1      = (¬1 AND (1 OR 1)) OR (¬(1 OR 1) AND 1)
= (0 AND 1) OR (0 AND 1) OR 1        = (0 AND 1) OR (0 AND 1)
= 0 OR 0 OR 1                        = 0 OR 0
= 1                                  = 0
```

Unless I'm forgetting some crucially pertinent axiom, I've confirmed that you need more context to evaluate the given expression.

<sup>(And, of course, examining the expression `A XOR B OR C` ∀`A`,`B`,`C` is of course substantially more tricky! But if the expression is ambiguous for just one value of all three inputs, then why bother checking for any others?)</sup>

This context is usually provided in language-specific evaluation-order rules. C-type languages [give `XOR` a low precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) (something Richie came to dislike); by contrast, *mathematical* convention [dictates a left-to-right associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#The_standard_order_of_operations) where no other axiom can be applied and an ambiguity is otherwise present.

So, basically, since we're ignoring language-specific rules, you'd probably go with `[I]`.

Answer (score 1):

Most languages would do XOR then OR; experienced coders will put parentheses in anyway just to make the intent clear.

Many more modern languages do what's called fast- or short-circuit- evaluation, so `0 & ?` is always `0`, so `?` will not be evaluated; same with `1 + ?`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a generally agreed upon order of precedence with logical operators. The evaluation would be entirely specific to a language.

Answer (score -1):

In c# for instance, the [Operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for bitwise operators is:

1. AND
2. XOR
3. OR

But this might be different for another language. If the precedence is the same, then the operations are executed from left to right. There is no logical XOR operator, but you can use  NOT EQUAL (!=) instead.

Comment: Your answer doesn't talk about Boolean algebra at all. The question is explicitly asking for language-agnostic rules.

Comment: @TomalakGeretkal: This not a mathematical forum. If this was a purely mathematical question, then it would have to be asked at [http://math.stackexchange.com/](http://math.stackexchange.com/). I assumed that the question would relate to programming in general. However, since there is no consensus about precedence of operators, I mentioned c# as an example.

Comment: Whether the question is on-topic or not, it's -- again -- explicitly about boolean algebra. That doesn't mean it has no bearing on programming, but it was stated that language-agnostic answers are sought. So, an answer about C# rules is not pertinent. It's also worth noting that SO is not a "forum" at all.